# Could the error "external symbol _cublasDestroy_v2@4" be caused because of improper use of CUDA

Tags: cuda, cublas

I get these errors when I try to compile a matrix CUBLAS operation:

```
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>executionU.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cublasDestroy_v2@4
1>executionU.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cublasSgemm_v2@56
1>executionU.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cublasCreate_v2@4
1>../../bin/win32/Release//executionU.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Does anybody know if this error could be caused by using version 4.1 and not the new 4.2 of CUDA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add cublas.lib to your linker dependencies.